# Looping to find out which array has the same digits as original array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

Given an "initial array" (say `[1, 2, 13]`) how can I implement a way to loop through an array of sub-arrays, all of which have the same size as the initial array (for example, `arr = [[2, 13, 1], [13, 1, 1], [13, 2, 2]]`) and find out if at least one sub-array has the same values as the values in the initial array, and the counts of each of those values is the same in both arrays?

In the above example `[1, 2, 13]` and `[2, 13, 1]` both have one `1`, one `2` and one `13`, so `true` should be returned. If the first element of `arr` were instead, say, `[2, 1, 1]`, `false` should be returned as no element of `arr` has counts of its elements that are the same as the counts of the elements in the initial array.

Comment: Do you want to find all the permutations of each element in the array? If so, hint: [`permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation).

Comment: I am precisely trying to find a way to do this without ```Array.permutation``` because for larger numbers permutation is computationally very expensive.

Comment: Your approach here of randomly picking digits and testing for matches is going to be exponentially less efficient.

Comment: You can *sort* the two lists, and then check if the sorted lists are equal.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This helped me immensely. Thanks!

Comment: @tadman, I edited the question. Please reconsider the hold.

Comment: jeporcher, I trust you will approve of my edit to your question. The fact that you accepted @Kache's answer gave me confidence that my understanding of the question is correct.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the edit! And there's nothing sad about a postdoc in philosophy learning to code, trust me. I'm enjoying myself a hell of a lot!

Comment: To avoid flagging it's usually best to express your question in terms of what input you have and what output you require in terms of actual Ruby code. The ambiguity here was if those arrays you're comparing to are generated, derived, or are instead given as input. When phrasing your question try and steer towards sketching it out as code, as an example with `def find_permutations(match, *list)` with a few demonstration calls, despite not having an implementation, would make your intent clear.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your input. Will keep it in mind from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming all the arrays are already in memory anyways, it's simplest just to do:

```
sorted_initial_arr = [1, 2, 3].sort
arr_list = [[2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1], [3, 2, 2]]

arr_list.any? { |arr| arr.sort == sorted_initial_arr }
```

more "conceptually":

```
# some function to do "unordered equality"
unordered_equality_to_inital_arr = ->(arr) { arr.sort == sorted_initial_arr }

# apply that function across the array of arrays
arr_list.any?(&unordered_equality_to_inital_arr)
```

The `unordered_equality_to_inital_arr` component could be implemented in several ways, e.g. using `permutation` as you mentioned, the differences being how they'd perform.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thoughtful response. I got the desired results comparing the sorted arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [[2, 3, 1, 3], [3, 1, 1, 3], [3, 2, 2, 1]]
target = [1, 2, 3, 2].group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {1=>[1], 2=>[2, 2], 3=>[3]}

arr.any? { |a| a.group_by(&:itself) == target }
  #=> true
```

Note

```
arr.map { |a| a.group_by(&:itself) }
  #=> [{2=>[2], 3=>[3, 3], 1=>[1]},
  #    {3=>[3, 3], 1=>[1, 1]}, 
  #    {3=>[3], 2=>[2, 2], 1=>[1]}]
{1=>[1], 2=>[2, 2], 3=>[3]} == {3=>[3], 2=>[2, 2], 1=>[1]}
  #=> true
```

The use of [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), being a single-pass calculation (for each element of `arr`), is more efficient than sorting. In terms of computational complexity, `group_by` is almost O(`n`) ("almost" as hash lookups are almost O(`1`)), whereas [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sort) (quicksort) is O(`n log n`), `n` being the size of an element of `arr`.

An alternative is to use a *counting hash*:

```
target = [1, 2, 3, 2].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }
  #=> {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1}
arr.any? { |a| a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 } == target }
  #=> true
```

which is also a single-pass operation.

The following may be even faster, as the comparison of each element of `arr` with `target` terminates as soon as it can be concluded that there is no match in the counts. For example, if, as before,

```
target
  #=> {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1}
```

and

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3]
```

it will be concluded that the there is no match as soon as the second `1` in `a` is examined. The calculation is as follows.

```
arr.any? do |a|
  t = target.dup
  a.each do |n|
    break false unless t.key?(n)
    t[n] > 1 ? (t[n] -= 1) : t.delete(n)
  end && t.empty?        
end
  #=> true
```

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks a lot for your considerate and thorough response.